# Microsoft Excel: Use OR Logic and multiple ranges with COUNTIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am analysing some form responses and want to count if someone has put a specific answer in a range of different boxes. I have attached an example to explain the logic.

[image: Table of responses]

When filling out address details people often put their county/region in the wrong box, or in multiple boxes, or leave multiple blank. I want to record people's responses in a table, like:

[image: COUNTIF table]

So for the number of people who's region is Buckinghamshire and like fish I want excel to count if any of the columns A:D contain "Buckinghamshire" and if column E contains "yes". Essentially, I want:

`=COUNTIFS(OR(A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D),"Buckinghamshire",E:E,"Yes")`

But that doesn't work; you can't have an OR inside a COUNTIF range. Some people have suggested doing a sum of multiple countifs but in this example that means people that have listed their county/region in two different columns would get counted twice, which is not what I want.

Is there a wise-crack solution that can cut out those duplicate responses? Or an alternative way to apply OR logic within a COUNTIF?

Comment: @MátéJuhász latest excel for O365, not sure which specifically that is

Comment: I think you will need a helper column with your `OR` statement.  Once that column contains the data you are looking for sum it up with the `SUMIFS` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the middle of making a reply while the other user replied, but anyway, you can also use SUM, like this:

```
=SUM((((A$2:A$5=$G$2)+(B$2:B$5=$G$2)+(C$2:C$5=$G$2)+(D$2:D$5=$G$2))>0)*($E$2:$E$5="Yes"))
```

[image]

Comment: Tidy solution. The power of the humble SUM. Thanks all for answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT to achieve your goal:

- for fish lovers: `=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$12=$G2)+($B$2:$B$12=$G2)+($C$2:$C$12=$G2)+(D2:D12=$G2))*($E$2:$E$12="Yes"))`
- those who don't like fish: `=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$12=$G2)+($B$2:$B$12=$G2)+($C$2:$C$12=$G2)+(E2:E12=$G2))*($E$2:$E$12="No"))`

Unfortunately it's not a very simple formula, it just implements the logic you described in your question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to filter the columns base on the Region criteria to return the result (yes/No), then sum the rows that correspond to the answer (Yes/No):

```
=SUM(IF(FILTER(E:E,(A:A=$G2)+(B:B=$G2)+(C:C=$G2)+(D:D=$G2))="Yes",1,"0"))
```

[image]